# asp.net core web app: MS Identity and OIDC at the same time: OIDC logout doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I have a (legacy) solution where a user is authenticated by Microsoft Identity in my own local SQL database. Now, the customer asks to access a foreign API, which is secured by 'Open ID Connect' (OIDC) with different credentials. Everything works as needed, but when the user logs out of the API, the OIDC logout process isn't initiated (no forward to OIDC logout page).

Extract of Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
  {
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOut";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
  });
     
  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // "Cookies"
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // "OpenIdConnect"
  })
  .AddJwtBearer(options => 
  {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidateAudience = true,
      ValidateLifetime = true,
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
      ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
  })
  .AddCookie(setup => setup.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionCookieLifetime))
  .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
  {
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = identityUrl;
    options.ClientId = clientId;
    options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Home/Index";
  };
}

public async Task Login()
{
  await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // "OpenIdConnect"
}

public async Task Logout()
{
  await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // "OpenIdConnect"
  //await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // "Cookies"
}
```

I use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect (5.0.17)` for OIDC.

`IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;` doesn't seem to work in my case.

I have created a sample web app with OIDC authentication only to scan the traffic (Wireshark) of a OIDC logout. But since it's https and doesn't run directly over the browser, there is no possibility to decipher the traffic.

What's the problem with the not working OIDC logout?
It's unusual to have a double authentication, but it should work, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the redirection code you put nor the return statement.

this will automatically redirect you to the Oidc server.
and in your client configuration you can put the `ClientPostLogoutRedirectUris` so that the Oidc can redirect you back to your page.

if you don't have control over the oidc to add the `ClientPostLogoutRedirectUris`  then it will be redirect the the oidc server's logout page only.

```
    public async Task Logout()
    {
       await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // "OpenIdConnect"
       await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // "Cookies"
    }
```

just make sure you are putting the right AuthenticationSchemes for each one.

**Edit :**

Those are the Steps to make the OIDC redirect the user back to your page:

1. At the OIDC you need to define the ClientPostLogoutRedirectUris related to the client you're using in your code.
2. Inside on `AddOpenIdConnect` you need to put the `SignedOutCallbackPath` like follows :
   `options.SignedOutCallbackPath=clientPostLogoutRedirectUri;`\

if you dont have access to add your clientPostLogoutRedirectUri to the OIDC server you can't redirect, and if the OIDC server youre using doesnt support redirection (in rare cases) you can't redirect.

**Long story short :** as a consumer of the service of OIDC all you can do is to put `SignedOutCallbackPath` on your `AddOpenIdConnect` if you put it and your OIDC server does not support it , it will not work.

Comment: Thanks, Ibrahim, for your response. You're right, my code doesn't need a RedirectToAction(..) hence the OIDC callback should redirect the user. My problem is: the **OIDC doesn't get a call to logout**.

Comment: I updated the answer , what your asking is not possible unless you have control over the OIDC , or at least know some one is

Comment: The failing logout seems to come from the missing OIDC identity once I have signed in on the MS identity. I assumed the platform is able to have several identities at the same time, since `ClaimsPrincipal.Identities` is an `IEnumberable<ClaimsIdentity>`.